# Как проставить в таблице 0 клиентам, в даты, когда они не приходили и 1, когда приходили? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица вида:

| Дата | Клиент | Выручка |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | Маша | 100 |
| 03.01.2021 | Маша | 200 |

Как проставить в таблице 0 клиентам, в даты, когда они не приходили и 1, когда приходили?
Чтобы получить таблицу вида:

| Дата | Клиент | Приходил |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | Маша | 1 |
| 02.01.2021 | Маша | 0 |
| 03.01.2021 | Маша | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
calendar AS ( SELECT MIN(`date`) datefrom, MAX(`date`) datetill
              FROM sourcetable 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT datefrom + INTERVAL 1 DAY, datetill
              FROM cte
              WHERE datefrom < datetill ),
users AS ( SELECT DISTINCT user
           FROM sourcetable )
SELECT users.user,
       calendar.datefrom `date`,
       sourcetable.`date` IS NULL attendance
FROM calendar
CROSS JOIN users
LEFT JOIN sourcetable ON users.user = sourcetable.user
                     AND calendar.datefrom = sourcetable.`date`;
```